# Find two subrings S and T such that S + T is not a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find two subrings S and T of the polynomial ring R[x,y] such that S + T is not a subring of R[x,y].

I was thinking of taking S to be the ring that consists of all powers of $\sqrt2$ and T to be the ring that consists of all powers of $\sqrt5$.  Then for S+T to be a subring you would need $(\sqrt2 +\sqrt5)^2=7 + 2\sqrt10$ to be in S+T, but $2\sqrt10$ isn't in S + T.

Is that correct?

Comment: Depending on what $R$ is, neither $\sqrt{2}$ nor $\sqrt{5}\in R$, so I'm not sure what you exactly mean. But your approach is reasonable; just adapt it to the polynomial rings you were given.

Comment: @rogerl Could you explain how to change it? This is a problem from a while ago and I'm struggling

Comment: Perhaps you should try taking $S = R[x]$ and $T=R[y]$.

Comment: @rogerl ok, but then why isn't S + T a ring?  Because $(p(x) + q(y))^2 = p(x)^2 + 2p(x)q(y) + q(y)^2$, but $2p(x)q(y)$ isn't in S+T?

Comment: @VinnyChase Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $R=\mathbb{R}$,this proof is in the right direction. However, your $S$ and $T$ as you've defined them aren't subrings: e.g. neither $-\sqrt{2}$ nor $1+\sqrt{2}$ is not an element of $S$ as you've defined it. Do you see how to fix this?

Also, you probably want to say "all *integer* powers of ...," since otherwise (when you fix the issue above) you get all of $\mathbb{R}$.

---

Of course, this is assuming that $R$ is meant to be $\mathbb{R}$. If not, of course, your idea doesn't work at all, and you'll need to think a bit more about what we know about $R[x, y]$ (HINT: think about the relationship between $R[x]$ and $R[x, y]$ ...).

Comment: So what would be good subrings to use?  I honestly don't see how to fix this

Comment: @VinnyChase Are you familiar with the word "generate" in this context (e.g. "the group generated by" or "ring generated by")?

Comment: yes I am familiar with rings "generated by"

Comment: @VinnyChase Well, can you see a way to go from your idea for $S$ to an actual subring which (for example) does contain all integer roots of $2$, but doesn't contain $\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure.  My best guess is $mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$

Comment: @VinnyChase I think you mean $\sqrt{2}$... Try it and see!